# Speller works for some words not others. Dont know where the problem is

Tags: c, hashtable, singly-linked-list, cs50

I am CS50 problem set 4, speller, hashtable version.

Code detects number of words correctly in dictionary and text. However it mis-spells words.

```
// Loads dictionary 
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // Initialize hash table
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        hashtable[i] = NULL;
    }

    // Open dictionary
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        unload();
        return false;
    }

    // Buffer for a word
    char word[LENGTH + 1];

    // Insert words into hash table
    while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
        int j = hash(word);

        // check if out of memory
        if (new_node == NULL)
        {
            unload();
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy(new_node->word, word);
            new_node->next = hashtable[j];
            hashtable[j] = new_node;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded 
{
    unsigned int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {

        node *cursor = hashtable[i];
        while (cursor != NULL)
        {
            cursor = cursor->next;
            count++;
        }
     }
    return count;
}


 // Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    int i = hash(word);
    node *chk = hashtable[i];

    while (chk != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(chk->word, word))
        {
            return true;
        }
        chk = chk->next;
    }
    return false;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    // TODO

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        node *cursor = hashtable[i];

        while (cursor != NULL)
        {
            node *temp = cursor;
            cursor = cursor->next;
            free(temp);
        }
    }
return true;
}
```

If large dictionary is selected, misspelled words are always 0 (whatever the text is), if small dictionary is selected (with cat.txt), it was showing as expected. Any custom made dictionary, shows some correct words as misspelled words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man strcmp` [emphasis added]:

> **RETURN VALUE**
>          The strcmp() and strncmp() functions **return an integer** less than, equal to, or
>          greater than zero if s1 (or the first n bytes thereof) is found, respectively,
>          to be less than, to match, or be greater than s2.

You could take a small custom made dictionary through debug50 and see what happens at this line:
 `if (strcmp(chk->word, word))`

Since `strcmp` returns an `int`, test it like an `int`, not a `bool`. And don't forget: the checker should be case *in*sensitive!